# magento downloadable products not able to download

Tags: magento-1.8, products, downloadable, download

downloadable products only worked once when i set the link to be downloaded able only once after that i couldnt download it with a different account

does the download limit apply to only one account or all accounts

so i set the product download limit to one then i was able to download it with the first account

i tried again with a second account and i received an error says "The link is not available."
that comes up after i click the product in the my downloadable products section of the account

Comment: Did the second account purchased the product? I don't think you fully understand how a downloadable product works.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the order is completed, at least invoiced. In other word for the link to work properly, the status have to be available, not pending.

May be too late but It will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer to this, but you set the Max. Downloads in the Catalog > Product Information > Downloadable Information tab in the admin tool. That field determines how many times each purchase can be downloaded. That selection is per account/purchase. You control how many downloads you can sell in total in the Product Information > Inventory tab under the Qty field. You can only download an item from the account that purchased it. If you are logged in to that account on different computers, then you could download it on multiple machines, IF the Max. Downloads is higher than 1.

Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

You can set:

> Catalog>Manage Products>Set Manage Invetory Stock to No